# How to use some flutter plugin as a dependency to a flutter package and use this package in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I am trying to make a single package for dealing with permissions and data flow for this I have used different plugins and packages as a dependency on this package. But some plugins throw errors of  [image: missing plugin exception].

Does anyone know the reason behind it? It's working fine before flutter version 3.0. But not working now.

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade dependencies?

Comment: I am using the latest dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with flutter activity binding.
I solved it by doing these steps.

1. Go to **your_app/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**
2. Search for activity tag.
3. Change android:name=".MainActivity" to android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands in the terminal;

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`

Comment: I already tried this, doesn't work also tried invalidating caches.